# Merging two tables in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in SQL Server 2008 R2. One is called `customer` and data in the table is like this:

[image]

The second table is called `Operators` and data looks like this:

[image]

The result should combine data from both tables and look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select brid, customer_id, 0 as account_id, customer_name, nic_no
from customers
union all
select brid, customer_id, account_id, (first_name + ' ' + last_name) as customer_name, nic_no
from operators;
```

Comment: thanks for solution.  Both Customer and Operators tables are referenced through through columns (BrID, CustomerID). Can we use join and COALESCE or some other functionality of sql server to get the desired result.

Comment: @SyedImranShah . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.  Please be sure that the explanation is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this as well ..

```
SELECT BrID
       ,Customer_Id
       ,0 as Account_Id
       ,Customer_Name as [Customer name]
       ,NIC_No
FROM Customer

UNION ALL

select BrID
       ,Customer_Id
       ,Account_Id
       ,CONCAT(First_Name,' ',Last_Name) as [Customer name]
       ,NIC_No
FROM Operator
```